# Position SVG to the left when embedded via img

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I'm embedding a SVG with a width of 100% and automatic height. The maximum height is 80% of the viewport.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        html, body{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;   
        }
        img{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            max-height: 80vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="example.svg">
</body>
</html>
```

If the SVG doesn't fit into the 80% of the viewport it'll be cropped by the specified maximum height. The problem is that this also centeres the SVG:

[image: centerd red area]

**What I need is to keep the embedding via `<img>` as this is what I receive from a CMS and position the SVG to the left like a `background-position: left top;` would do. How to position the `<img>` contents to the left, even if the image is cropped?**

Comment: The white space is in your svg. So you have to use some software like illustrator or some online tool  to remove that white space..

Comment: No, I've checked the file with Illustrator and the whitespace is generated by the CSS styles / HTML. It's not included in the SVG!

Comment: can you share a fiddle demo.. ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to add `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"` to root svg element of your svg file, like this.

```
<svg width="200px" height="200px" 
  viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Do you want preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" or  preserveAspectRatio="none" ?

Comment: preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" works, update your answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing:

```
float:left;
```

Comment: This doesn't help because the image has a width of 100%, so it doesn't matter whether there is float:left;, display:block or display:inline-block